# Changing font color of specific page

Tags: css, wordpress

I try to edit the color of an element on a specific page. Been doing it according to information from this website using additional CSS to add the following: .page-id-9234 .introBox h2 { color: #FFFFFF!important; }

However, this does not seem to work yet.

Been testing on this page: https://bconnectlivechat.nl/test-salespage-futy/

Comment: The `.page-id-9234` is not on the page you provide. How did you added this custom css ?

Comment: I added it in the theme editor, customizer. Indeed the problem is with targeting the page as leaving the page targeting does result in a white color on this element on the whole website. However, I need it just on that one specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your active theme's functions.php

```
function css_for_specific_page() {
    global $wp;
    if ( $wp->request == 'test-salespage-futy' ) { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .introBox h2 {
                color: #FFFFFF!important;
            }
        </style>
    <?php } 
}
add_action('wp_head', 'css_for_specific_page');
```

Comment: please explain why and how this code works and if this function might get overwritten by any future WP update?

Comment: I was actually looking for a code to add in extra additional CSS in stead of changing the php. I saw that there should be options to do this. 

However I do understand that this should possibly work as it is function for specific page. Still using the wp request will cause that changing pagetitle results in loss of the function, right?

Comment: @MarcLonsain Is this your page id 9234? And in an alternate way you can also try this, in this case even if you update page title then id will remain same in that case.
if ( get_the_id() == 9234 ) { ?>

Comment: That might work. However I still would like to do it in theme editor additional CSS in stead of in functions php. Also because I am not the webdeveloper myself and did not write that code. 

Do you have a suggestion for that as well? It should be possible..